# Hard coding a rectangle with a border

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-activity

I would like to draw a grey rectangle which has a red border around it using XML only but I've seen this being done in many different ways and so I'd like someone to tell me which way is the best in order to achieve this? Below is my code but I want to know if there is an easier way. No java please. I only want xml.

```
            <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:background="@color/red"
            android:layout_weight=".25">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="7dp"
                android:layout_height="7dp"
                android:background="@color/grey"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

**Layout not aligning**

[image: align error]

```
        <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@color/grey"
        android:layout_weight=".25" >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="3"
            android:textColor="@color/black"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:background="@color/red"
            android:layout_weight=".25">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="7dp"
                android:layout_height="7dp"
                android:background="@color/grey"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:background="@color/red"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="12dp"
                android:layout_height="7dp"
                android:background="@color/grey"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:background="@color/red"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="12dp"
                android:layout_height="7dp"
                android:background="@color/grey"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:background="@color/red"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="12dp"
                android:layout_height="7dp"
                android:background="@color/grey"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:background="@color/red"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:padding="1.5dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/grey"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:background="@color/red"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="12dp"
                android:layout_height="7dp"
                android:background="@color/grey"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your drawable
rectangle.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 

<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"   >

    <solid
        android:color="#D7D5D6" >
    </solid>

    <stroke
        android:width="0.5dp"
        android:color="#ff0000" >
    </stroke>

 </shape>
```

And your layout.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
    >
    </LinearLayout>
```

You can change your desired color code and width of the border.

Answer (score 1):

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:background="#ff0000"
android:padding="10dp">

<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="#f4f4f4"
    >

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: OK do you know how I can horizontal align my relative 30% of the way from the left side rather than in the middle? Please check my code above titled **Layout not aligning**

Comment: i think that seems pretty out of syllabus .... as there is no unit for %..and the relative layout is not fixed...... i think this looks impossible using xml....but through java code we can do it...

Answer (score 0):

LinearLayout and RelativeLayout are viewgroups. Instead them use simple View with

> android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
>   attribute (see next answer).

Comment: please don't refer to the next answer (which relies on sorting), copy paste the necessary code instead.